# SQL Server 2014 - How to find Distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have a list of Contact that have First Names, Last Names and Email addresses. Some Email addresses have multiple First and Last Names. I am more concerned about the Email Addresses. I really just want the top name for that Email Address.

**My Code doesn't work obviously:**

```
SELECT Salutation  
, FirstName  
, LastName  
, EmailAddress  
FROM Contact  
--GROUP BY EmailAddress  ---I know a Group by will surely help
```

**I have tried**

```
SELECT max(Salutation)
    ,max(FirstName)
    ,max(LastName)
    ,max(EMailAddress)
FROM Contact
WHERE EMailAddress NOT LIKE ''
GROUP BY EMailAddress
```

This worked but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: How do you define **top** name?

Comment: Using `max()` for names across duplicates can get you records with mixed names. e.g. 'Aaron Bertrand' and 'Itzik Ben-Gan' would get you 'Itzik Bertrand'. If you have mixed Salutation then you will always get 'Mrs.' from 'Mr.' and 'Mrs.'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you define **top name**?

Using `max()` for names can easily return results with mixed names, e.g. 'Aaron Bertrand' and 'Itzik Ben-Gan' would return 'Itzik Bertrand'. If you have mixed `Salutation` then you will always get 'Mrs.' from 'Mr.' and 'Mrs.' which might not be appropriate either.

---

using [**`top with ties`**](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option) and [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
select top 1 with ties
    Salutation
  , FirstName
  , LastName
  , EmailAddress
from contact
where EmailAddress <> ''
order by row_number() over (
  partition by EmailAddress
  order by FirstName /* your 'top' criteria here, FirstName is a placeholder */
  );
```

[**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) version:

```
select distinct
    x.Salutation
  , x.FirstName
  , x.LastName
  , t.EmailAddress
from contact t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        i.Salutation
      , i.FirstName
      , i.LastName
    from t as i
    where i.EmailAddress = t.EmailAddress
    order by i.FirstName
    ) as x
where t.EmailAddress <> ''
```

[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) with [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) version:

```
;with cte as (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
             partition by EmailAddress
                 order by FirstName
            )
  from contact
  where EmailAddress <> ''
)
select  
    Salutation
  , FirstName
  , LastName
  , EmailAddress
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

I prefer using common table expressions, but the query inside it works just as well in the `from` clause:

[**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a subquery version:

```
select  
    Salutation
  , FirstName
  , LastName
  , EmailAddress
from (
  select *
    , rn = row_number() over (
             partition by EmailAddress
                 order by FirstName
            )
    from contact
    where EmailAddress <> ''
  ) s
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your first code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT Salutation  
, FirstName  
, LastName  
, EmailAddress  
FROM Contact  
WHERE EmailAddress IS NULL 
      OR ID IN
      (SELECT MAX(ID)
       FROM Contact  
       WHERE EmailAddress IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY EmailAddress)
```

This will give you the last one added for each email address.

Comment: The table doesn't have an ID column, apparently. 'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Invalid column name 'ID'. '

Comment: @user1777929 I just used "ID" b/c you didn't list what the ID column was really named. If you have an id column with a different name then just use that.  If you have a LastEdit DateTime column you could also use that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It definitely helped.